# Control.MouseWheel Event

Tags: c#, events, scroll, mouseevent, mousewheel

I created a simple application for zooming the image inside the picture box with the mouse wheel. It runs perfectly at my development laptop (Win10). But when I run it on my desktop PC (Win7), the zooming (using mouse wheel) function does not work.

Below is my snippet of my implementation:

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 0);
        this.pictureBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(493, 583);
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseDown);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseMove);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseUp);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseWheel);
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        this.panel1.AutoSize = true;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 2);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(714, 593);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(719, 594);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

private float ZOOM = 1.5f
private void pictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Focus();
        if (e.Delta < 0) //ZoomIn
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse Wheel Zoom In");

            if ((pictureBox1.Width < panel1.Width) && (pictureBox1.Height < panel1.Height))
            {
                pictureBox1.Width = Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Width * ZOOM);
                pictureBox1.Height = Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Height * ZOOM);
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                this.Refresh();                    
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //ZoomOut
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse Wheel Zoom Out");
            if ((pictureBox1.Width > panel1.Width) &&
            (pictureBox1.Height > panel1.Height))
            {
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pictureBox1.Width = Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Width / ZOOM);
                pictureBox1.Height = Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Height / ZOOM);
            }
        }
    }
```

I think that it is the problem with the Control.MouseWheel event on my desktop PC. When I was debugging, this event never came up although I already focused or clicked inside the picture box. When I tried other implementation using implementation by filtering the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a;` message, it works both on my laptop and my desktop. Any idea why these different behaviors are happening? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Win10 has a system option named "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them”.  Turned on by default.  Win7 doesn't have that.  And neither the PictureBox nor the Panel are ever going to be "active".  You could subscribe the PictureBox' MouseMove event and call its Focus() method as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. I added the MouseHover event and it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that Win 10 has a system option called  "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them”. That's why my previous code is working only in Win 10 machine. I added the below lines to fix it. Thanks @HansPassant for the tip.

```
    private void picBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picBox.Focus();
    }
```